# Access variable in anonymous function (semi Shopify-related)

Tags: function, shopify, anonymous-function

Shopify stores load their apps within an anonymous async function, as seen below. I build themes and the biggest performance issue is the number of apps loaded on a page (10+ all the time).

I want to build a small extension that counts the number of strings in the `url` variable below. Super hacky options happily accepted.

```
<script>
(function() {
  function asyncLoad() {
    var urls = [];
  };
  if(window.attachEvent) {
    window.attachEvent('onload', asyncLoad);
  } else {
    window.addEventListener('load', asyncLoad, false);
  }
})();
</script>
```

Comment: If you can modify your code, removing var from urls will make it global variable. Or you can just add it to window object.

Comment: Unfortunately I can't - this is all defined by Shopify which is what makes it so tricky

Answer (score -1):

Arrays have a length. Since your variable url is an array, you can probably get away with url.length as a count of the number of elements in the variable.